# Which way is better for db handler?

Tags: php, object-oriented

Is it a bad idea for a model class hold the db handler as a property? Example code are as below. I think the second is better, but the first is not so bad in my opinion.

First:

```
class ActiveModel {
    protected $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = DbFactory::get('Foo');
    }

    public function save() {
        //use $this->db to do the job;
        ....
    }
}
```

Second:

```
class ActiveModel {

    public function save($db = null) {
        if ($db === null) {
            $db = DbFactory::get('Foo');
        }
        //then use $db to do the job;
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is fine and very convenient to keep the database handler as a property.  However, you should pass it in the constructor via [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), rather than call it's factory method inside the class.  This can ease unit testing when you need to mock a database connection object.

```
public function __construct($db) {
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But when dependency injection is not used, I need pass it to constructor every time. When by calling the factory method, I just need change the setting of DbFactory to let it give the mock db connection object.

Comment: Also, when doing automated testing, if DbFactory::get('Foo') becomes expensive your test suite will run much slower.